# WSO2 DAS: Removing Gadgets

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I'm evaluating WSO2 DAS 3.0.1. But can't find a way to remove gadgets created in the dashboard web portal.

Is there a way to delete them (either from the web UI or via command line)? I've looked through the documentation and cant really find out how to do it - aside from in their older BAM product where they could be removed from the Gadget Repository menu, which isn't in DAS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For DAS 3.0.1 you cannot delete gadgets from the management console or terminal. You can manually remove them by deleting gadget files located in following directory

```
<DAS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/portal/store/carbon.super/gadget
```